# Primeness of an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $k$ be a field and $x_1,  x_2, ...,x_n$ are independent over $k$. Is there a simple argument to prove that the ideal $\langle x_1-x_2, x_2-x_3,\dots,x_{n-1}-x_n\rangle$ is a prime ideal of $k[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n]$? (Note that it can be checked easily by Macaulay2)

Is the result true when $n$ is infinite?

Answer (score 2):

If $R$ is any commutative ring, a ring homomorphism $\varphi\colon k[x_1,x_2,\dotsc]\to R$ (any number of indeterminates, even infinite) is determined by the action on $k$ (so the restriction should be a ring homomorphism $k\to R$) and by the action on each indeterminate.

Consider the homomorphism $\varphi\colon k[x_1,x_2,\dotsc]\to k[y]$ defined to be the identity on $k$ and such that $\varphi(x_i)=y$.

Clearly, $x_i-x_{i-1}\in\ker\varphi$, for each $i>1$, and $\varphi$ is surjective. If we show that
$$
\ker\varphi=\langle x_{i}-x_{i-1}:1<i\le n\rangle
$$
(the $\le n$ condition to be omitted in the infinite case), the ideal is prime because $k[y]$ is a domain.

The inclusion $\langle x_{i}-x_{i-1}:i>1\rangle\subseteq\ker\varphi$ has already been proved. Suppose $f\in\ker\varphi$. Since $f$ depends only on finitely many indeterminates, we can assume $f\in k[x_1,\dots,x_m]$, where $m$ is the largest index that actually appears in $f$ (if $f$ is constant, then $f=0$ and there's nothing to prove).

If $m=1$, then $\varphi(f)=0$ is a contradiction. Thus $m>1$.

We can write $f=(x_m-x_{m-1})g+r$, where $r$ only depends possibly on $x_1,\dots,x_{m-1}$. Applying $\varphi$ gives
$$
0=\varphi(f)=(y-y)\varphi(g)+\varphi(r)
$$
and so induction says $r\in\langle x_{i}-x_{i-1}:i>1\rangle$, so also $f\in\langle x_{i}-x_{i-1}:i>1\rangle$.

Comment: You use induction in an essential way. Does it mean that the result is not true for polynomial rings with uncountably many indeterminates $k[x_i \mid i \in I]$ (the corresponding ideal being $\langle x_i - x_j \mid i,j \in I \rangle$)? Or does it have to so with the well-ordering of $\Bbb N$, rather than with its countability?

Comment: Why can you write $f$ as $(x_m - x_{m-1}) g + r$ with $r$ independent of $x_m$? I agree that you may write it as $x_m g + r = (x_m - x_{m-1}) g + x_{m-1} g + r$, but since $g$ may contain $x_m$, so will $x_{m-1} g$. It is as if you performed the Euclidean division of $f$ by $x_m - x_{m-1}$, but $k[x_1, \dots, x_{m-1}]$ is not a Euclidean ring, so what are you really doing?

Comment: @AlexM. I do polynomial division in $k[x_1,\dots,x_{m-1}][x_m]$ and the degree of $x_m-x_{m-1}$ (with respect to $x_m$) is $1$. So the remainder has degree in $x_m$ less than $1$.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but is this sort of division allowed? When one learns about Euclidean domains, one of the main examples studied is $k[X]$ with $k$ a *field*. I have never asked myself so far why, but when $k$ is not a field (as is the case here for $k[x_1, \dots, x_{m-1}]$), $k[X]$ is no longer Euclidean - so what do you use to perform your Euclidean division in the absence of a Euclidean norm? (It seems that "the degree in $x_m$" is not a norm - I do not know why.)

Comment: @AlexM. You can always do long division in $R[x]$, where $R$ is a domain, if the divisor is a monic polynomial. Just go through the proof of the division algorithm in $k[x]$ to see why: at some point you have to multiply by the inverse of the leading coefficient of the divisor, but if the polynomial is monic there's nothing to do. That's the only point where an inverse is needed. Thus, if $f(x)\in R[x]$ and $g(x)\in R[x]$ is monic, there exist $q(x),r(x)$ such that $f(x)=g(x)q(x)+r(x)$ and the degree of $r$ is less than the degree of $g$. In our case, $R=k[x_1,\dots,x_{m-1}]$ and $x=x_m$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(x_1 - x_2, \dots, x_{n-1} - x_n) \cong k[x_1] $$

and since $k[x_1]$ is an integral domain, our ideal is indeed prime. The same is true for $n$ infinite.

Answer (score 0):

As the ideal is also $\;(x_2-x_1,x_3-x_1,\dots, x_n-x_1)$, the quotient is clearly isomorphic to $\;k[x_1]$, hence the ideal is prime. The isomorphism is induced by the homorphism
\begin{align*}
k[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]&\longrightarrow k[x_1],\\
p(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]&\longmapsto p(x_1,0,\dots,0).
\end{align*}

If ‘$n$ is infinite’, i.e. if we consider the ring $\;k[x_n]_{n\in\mathbf N}$, the same argument works, since each polynomial involves only a finite number of indeterminates.